# Neural Network with correlated features

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

Is there a Neural Network algorithm that supports adding features on the fly (non-fixed feature set) and where it does not assume features isn't correlated with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't think you can add features on fly, becouse NN as many other algorithm work with vector of input vector with same size, although it is sparse vectors. You can train with one feature set, then store weights add new features and start new training I think it will coverege much faster than first one.
2. NN(of first order) is work like Logistic regression and solve problem for global maximum, there are no assumption about features at all, just finding function which is related to probabilistic distribution which maximize likehood of training data, unlike Naive Bayes where each propability is  calulcated separetly and then they combined with independence assumption.